# Gnome, night light and dual monitor

Tags: nvidia, gnome3, multi-monitor

When I turn the [night light](https://github.com/TimurKiyivinski/gnome-shell-night-light-slider-extension) option in `Gnome 3.20.2` it only activates in one monitor and it leaves my second one with the normal white balance.  This renders the option unusable.

I am currently using NVidia's proprietary drivers on version `415.27`.

Am I missing some "magic option" to enable this feature on both monitors?

Comment: It is a long standing bug see https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-settings-daemon/issues/6